# How to Enable Hive Support for spark in spark-shell (spark 2.1.1)

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to enable Hive support for the spark object in spark-shell, but it doesn't work.  I'm using Hortonworks HDP.  The following is what I get when I try to enable Hive support:

```
scala> val spark3 = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport.getOrCreate
17/10/24 21:30:28 WARN SparkSession$Builder: Using an existing SparkSession; some configuration may not take effect.
spark3: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@22f8be7c

scala> spark3.catalog
res3: org.apache.spark.sql.catalog.Catalog = org.apache.spark.sql.internal.CatalogImpl@49c13ecd
```

Comment: Umm... Its working. Have you tried  `spark.sql()`?

Comment: Sorry about the code, but spark3.catalog shows the same thing as spark.catalog.

Comment: The thing is that spark.cataglog is showing the type of the catalog which is org.apache.spark.sql.internal.CatalogImpl. If enableHiveSupport() is effective, then it should show org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionCatalog.

Comment: What reference do you have that `HiveSessionCatalog` would be printed? That class doesn't exist in that package, if at all. https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/package-summary.html

Answer (score 3):

In HDP, `spark-shell` already creates a valid SparkSession with Hive support.

You got it warning saying that `getOrCreate` used the existing session

You can try

```
spark.sql("show tables").show()
```

Also, you're using `spark` instead of `spark3`, so it's not clear what `spark.catalog` was going to show you other than that Object's toString info

Comment: I think spark.sql() works because SparkSession internally implements a version of Hive; so, I think that's why spark.sql(), spark.catalog and stuff like that work.

Comment: "SparkSession internally implements a version of Hive" ... Not quite. The Spark Thrift Server is compatible with Hive. The default metastore used by Spark is an embedded Derby database. In HDP, the `hive-site.xml` is placed and read from `$SPARK_HOME/conf`, which is read when `enableHiveSupport` is called, but that is already done in spark-shell, last time I checked